# Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`, AssertionError

Tags: python, mysql, django

> AssertionError:Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or
>   `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view

views.py

```
# Create your views here.
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.status import (
   HTTP_200_OK, HTTP_201_CREATED, HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
)

import MySQLdb
from testpro.settings import connection
cur, conn = connection()

class Product_ListAPIView(ListAPIView):
   def get(self,request,format=None):
       cur,conn = connection()
       query = ''' SELECT * FROM products'''
       try:
           with conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:
               cursor.execute(query)
               result = cursor.fetchall()
               data = list(result)
               print(request.data)
           return Response({"data":result},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
       except Exception as e:
           print(e)
```

I think the connection is proper but I am not sure why I am getting this error, it would be great if anyone can help me figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: I guess an error is raise inside the `try` block and therefore no `Response` instance is returned

Comment: @Tal my thought also. Does it still happen when you return a Response in the except block also?

Comment: you have not returned anything in except block. try this in except block. return Response({"data":"except block"})

Comment: @Tal yeah there was an error in try block. when i execute try block it's worked properly. but i didn't get what was the error in try block?